# Approximation question: why $y(x)=(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+x})^2\approx0.25\times r^{\frac{-8}{3}}\times x^ \frac{2}{3} $

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I have a problem as follows. 
  The formula  is below: 
                   $$y(x)=\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+x}\right)^2$$
where $r\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

*Why the formula above can be approximated by the following formula:* 
                        $$y(x)=\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+x}\right)^2\approx0.25\times r^{\frac{-8}{3}}\times x^ \frac{2}{3}    $$
  I want to know the process of specific speculation.

Comment: Approximated where?  When $x$ is close to $0$?

Comment: Is there any condition about the range of $x$?

Comment: @guest   approximation formula is 0.25.....I want to know the process.

Comment: @Bob Jones .The range of x is from 0 to 100.